# can i read the deleted statuses on twitter with ruby?

Tags: ruby, twitter, tweets

I would like to read the deleted statuses on twitter since i can already have the user_id and status_id of the deleted tatus using "on_delete" method.

here is my code:

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'tweetstream'
   TweetStream::Client.new(USER,PASS).follow(3331681,15846407,30592818,21249843,1367531,428333,  196218494,82158673,   :delete => Proc.new{ |status_id, user_id| puts "#{status_id}, #{user_id}"}) do |status|

#is it a retweet
rt=!defined?(status.method_missing("retweeted_status",status.id).class).nil?
puts "retweet?:"
puts rt.inspect 

if status.in_reply_to_screen_name.nil?    
 if rt
   puts "Retweeted by :#{status.user.screen_name}"  
 else
   puts "Screen name :#{status.user.screen_name}" 
 end
else
  puts "From :#{status.user.screen_name} to #{status.in_reply_to_screen_name}"
end
 puts "Text:#{status.text}"
 puts "#{status.created_at}"
 puts '*' * 7
 puts "user id:#{status.user.id}"
 puts "to :#{status.in_reply_to_user_id}"
 puts '--' * 25
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. This is a constraint of the Twitter API rather than any Ruby library. It used to be possible but has since been fixed, breaking tweet recovery services such as tweleted.com in the process.